# Setting Message property in rfhUtil

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-7

I found in certain codes that given to me is    message.getStringProperty(MESSAGE_TYPE)

but my question is where the property is set in rfhUtil tool

please guide me..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set message type using MsgType combo box on MQMD tab of RFHUTIL.

Comment: Thank you .. please let me how to set message ? as it is showing "1 Request","112 FR_MQE" etc . so how to set message as if i want to set ABC=DEF..??

Comment: You can choose any one of the types available that suits the message requirements. For most cases type 8 is suitable.